# Are there software developers in Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, computers, lcars

Starfleet personell obviously uses a lot of software (e. g. LCARS) on their vessels, stations, handheld and wearable devices.

Thus, it would seem to me that there must be a lot of software engineers and developers in Starfleet, that develop and maintain all this software. However, none of the main characters calls themselves a software engineer.

Are there any known software engineers in Starfleet? Where are Starfleet's software engineers?